# "The operation can't be completed because you don't have the necessary permission." when modifying ANY file/folder on MacOS Ventura 13.5.2 (Apple M1)

Tags: mac

I am unable to modify the permissions on ANY folder above a locked file in my applications folder on my MacBook Pro M1. I am the only administrator. The computer technically belongs to my organization but I removed it from the MDM system. I'm not quite sure why it's happening, although I believe it might be caused by the presence of one locked file I was unable to remove by any means: `macappproxy.app` in my applications folder. Is it possible that the presence of a locked file in a subfolder could affect my ability to change settings in the root folder? I have tried every solution I could find and none of them have worked for me. I am also unable to unlock the `macappproxy.app` file (also not sure why). I turned off `csrutil` in reboot and attempted every command I could think to modify the permissions from `chmod 755` to `chflags noschg`/`chflags nouchg`. Also tried to `rm` the file directly and `rmdir` the folder that contains its data and the app itself, to no avail. There are no remaining MDM profiles, and nothing with App Management or Full Disk Access permissions (except for `sshd-keygen-wrapper`, `defaults` and terminal, but that's not a concern). So I guess my question(?s) is this: is the locked file the root of my problems? How do I remove it? If I can't, how do I get around this odd block of being unable to modify file settings? Thanks!

Comment: You can't 'remove' it from the MDM, only the company can release it. You're going to have to fess up & let them fix it. We cannot answer IT-related questions, sorry.

Comment: Can you modify files in your own home directory?

Comment: @Spiff Yes, I can. I just cannot edit the permissions on root folders above the locked file.

Comment: No-one can edit root level data structures, SIP on or off. The system volume is signed & sealed. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secd698747c9/web